# match count from neo4j and python

Tags: python, neo4j

given this code block

```
                parent_node_count = db.run(f"MATCH(parentNode) WHERE "
                              f"parentNode.LC = '{x[4]}' "
                              f"AND parentNode.U = '{x[5]}' "
                              f"AND parentNode.R = '{x[6]}' "
                              f"AND parentNode.Type = 'Parent' "
                              f"AND parentNode.Deck_Set = '{outline}' "
                              f" return parentNode")
            n = 0

            for record in parent_node_count:
                print(record["parent_node_count"]["id"])
                n = n + 1

            print("total number of records : " + str(n))
            total = int(n)
```

How do I get the number of matches from the MATCH query?

In the code provided, it always returns 0,
and I've check it in the browser, and the count from the match does not equal zero.

Comment: You are accessing `parent_node_count` instead of `parentNode` from the record. Doesn't this fail in general? I am not a Python expert, but it could lead to the problem that `n` never gets increased.

Comment: in the for line, or the print line?

Comment: The print statement in the for loop. As I said, no idea of this breaks the loop with a silent error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable parent_node_count is a neo4j.work.result.Result object and it does not contain the object id. You need to add it in the cypher query and access it via record.data() object.  See example below:

```
    parent_node_count = tx.run(f"MATCH(parentNode) WHERE "
                          f"parentNode.LC = '{x[4]}' "
                          f"AND parentNode.U = '{x[5]}' "
                          f"AND parentNode.R = '{x[6]}' "
                          f"AND parentNode.Type = 'Parent' "
                          f"AND parentNode.Deck_Set = '{outline}' "
                          f" return parentNode, ID(parentNode) AS id")
    print(parent_node_count)
    n = 0

    for record in parent_node_count:
        print(record.data()["parentNode"])
        print(record.data()["id"])
        n = n + 1

    print("total number of records : " + str(n))
    total = int(n)


Result:
<neo4j.work.result.Result object at 0x7ff6cd035f60>    <- parent_node_count
{'Latitude': 28.5553263, 'Longitude': 68.2132128, 'Name': 'Dayna'} <- record
321  <- id
{'Latitude': 54.1863169, 'Longitude': 19.7204087, 'Name': 'Dione'} <- record
333  <- id
total number of records : 2
```

Comment: Sorry Jose,  coded as exactly as your demo, no printing of the records in the record in parent_node_count loop, and n is always zero.

Comment: Please give me your entire script. As you can see on my sample result, it works for me.

Comment: When the parent_node_count is printed, what do you see?

Comment: This is what i used to get the results i was needing             parent_nodes = db.run(f"MATCH(parent) where parent.NodeType = 'Parent'"
                              f"AND parent.LC = '{property_lc}' "
                              f"AND parent.U  = '{property_u}' "
                              f"AND parent.Deck_Set = '{property_Deck_Set}' "                              
                              f"return parent")
        parent_results = [record for record in parent_nodes.data()]
        print("total number of records : " + str(len(parent_results)))